# What build configuration for React on Azure Static Web Apps?

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-static-web-app

I have seemingly tried everything and see conflicting instructions on deploying a React app (without API) to Azure Static Web Apps even from Microsoft. Has anyone done this successfully?

The latest doc I've used is:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/get-started-portal?tabs=react&pivots=github

which is for creating the SWA in the portal though I've used others as well with problems.

I've now arrived at this error:

```
    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
    npm ERR! errno 1
    npm ERR! percentage-calculator@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
    npm ERR! Exit status 1
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the percentage-calculator@0.1.0 build script.
    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /github/home/.npm/_logs/2022-07-12T19_38_33_349Z-debug.log
    ---End of Oryx build logs---

    Oryx has failed to build the solution.
```

Here is my file structure if that matters:

```
react-app ->src ->components ->index.js,App.js etc..
          ->public ->index.html etc..
          ->build (build is gitignored)
          ->node_modules etc..
```

My azurestaticwebapps... yml file contains:

```
app_location: "/"
api_location: ""
output_location: "build"
```

https://github.com/markhardy/percentage-calculator/runs/7308960687?check_suite_focus=true

Can someone explain what I'm doing wrong? I'm at a loss at this point especially with conflicting instructions from Microsoft.

Answer (score 2):

Seems you have warnings in your code, so the compiler doesn't like it.
Simply change the yml file as below:

under build_and_deploy_job, add:
env:
CI: false

This will stop treating warnings as errors.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anyone done this successfully?

- We have followed the same [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/static-web-apps/get-started-portal?tabs=react&pivots=github) which you have provided and able to build and deploy `React static web App` from portal without any issues.

***Build and Deploy Job:***
[image]

***`package.json` file:***

```json
{  
"name": "hello",  
"version": "0.1.0",  
"private": true,  
"dependencies": {  
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",  
"@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",  
"@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",  
"react": "^16.12.0",  
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",  
"react-scripts": "3.4.0"  
},  
"scripts": {  
"start": "react-scripts start",  
"build": "react-scripts build",  
"test": "react-scripts test",  
"playwright_test": "playwright test",  
"eject": "react-scripts eject"  
},  
"eslintConfig": {  
"extends": "react-app"  
},  
"browserslist": {  
"production": [  
">0.2%",  
"not dead",  
"not op_mini all"  
],  
"development": [  
"last 1 chrome version",  
"last 1 firefox version",  
"last 1 safari version"  
]  
},  
"devDependencies": {  
"@playwright/test": "^1.22.2"  
}  
}
```

- Try to add `devDependencies` in your `package.json` file and check once.

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/fsevents):

- As per this [Document](https://exerror.com/npm-warn-optional-skipping-optional-dependency-fsevents1-2-13/), we can add `optionalDependencies` in your `package.json` file or can run `npm install -f`.

Please refer [Troubleshooting deployment and runtime errors for Static Web Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/troubleshooting) for more information.

Comment: The same issue persists even after adding devDependencies as you have written above and npm install -f. Could this be a file structure issue? My app_location (in the .yml file) is supposed to be where my HTML and Javascript files are located but create-react-app created a src folder with js files and a public folder with index.html